# Web Crawler To get Links From New Website

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the links from a news website page(from one of its archives). I wrote the following lines of code in Python:

`main.py` contains :

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2010/06/19/"

br =  mechanize.Browser()
htmltext = br.open(url).read()

articletext = ""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
for tag in soup.findAll('li', attrs={"data-section":"Business"}):
    articletext += tag.contents[0]

print articletext
```

An example of the object in tag.contents[0] :
        `<a href="http://www.thehindu.com/business/itc-to-issue-11-bonus/article472545.ece" target="_blank">ITC to issue 1:1 bonus</a>`

But on running it I am getting the following error :

```
File "C:\Python27\crawler\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    text = articletext.getArticle(url)
  File "C:\Python27\crawler\articletext.py", line 23, in getArticle
    return getArticleText(htmltext)
  File "C:\Python27\crawler\articletext.py", line 18, in getArticleText
    articletext += tag.contents[0]
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Tag' objects
```

Can someone help me to sort it out ?? I am new to Python Programming. thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using link_dictionary vaguely. If you are not using it for reading purpose then try the following code :

```
 br =  mechanize.Browser()
 htmltext = br.open(url).read()

 articletext = ""
 for tag_li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={"data-section":"Op-Ed"}):
    for link in tag_li.findAll('a'):
        urlnew = urlnew = link.get('href')
        brnew =  mechanize.Browser()
        htmltextnew = brnew.open(urlnew).read()            
        articletext = ""
        soupnew = BeautifulSoup(htmltextnew)
        for tag in soupnew.findAll('p'):
            articletext += tag.text
        print re.sub('\s+', ' ', articletext, flags=re.M)
```

Note : `re` is for regulare expression. for this you import the module of `re`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you may want to try accessing the text inside the list item like so:

```
for tag in soup.findAll('li', attrs={"data-section":"Business"}):
    articletext += tag.string
```

---

**Edited: General Comments on getting links from a page**

Probably the easiest data type to use to gather a bunch of links and retrieve them later is a dictionary.

To get links from a page using BeautifulSoup, you could do something like the following:

```
link_dictionary = {}
with urlopen(url_source) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        link_dictionary[link.string] = link.get('href')
```

This will provide you with a dictionary named `link_dictionary`, where every key in the dictionary is a string that is simply the text contents between the `<a> </a>` tags and every value is the the value of the `href` attribute.

---

**How to combine this what your previous attempt**

Now, if we combine this with the problem you were having before, we could try something like the following:

```
link_dictionary = {}
for tag in soup.findAll('li', attrs={"data-section":"Business"}):
    for link in tag.findAll('a'):
        link_dictionary[link.string] = link.get('href')
```

If this doesn't make sense, or you have a lot more questions, you will need to experiment first and try to come up with a solution before asking another **new, clearer question.**

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.. although what I actually want is to get the links in `href` in some kind of an array or list.. can u help me out ?

Comment: I made an edit to my post that may help you get going in the right direction, but if it doesn't help, you will need to come up with a better question (and you'll have to do some experimentation first so you have a clear, concise question).

Comment: okay, I think I understand now what you're trying to do. See final edit above.

Comment: But I was unable to anything printed if I used `attrs={"data-section":"Chennai"}` instead of `attrs={"data-section":"Business"}`. Can you tell me the reason ?? I tried different methods but was unable to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the powerful XPath query language with the faster [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) module. As simple as that:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

url = 'http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2010/06/19/'
html = etree.HTML(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

for link in html.xpath("//li[@data-section='Business']/a"):
    print '{} ({})'.format(link.text, link.attrib['href'])
```

**Update for @data-section='Chennai'**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

url = 'http://www.thehindu.com/template/1-0-1/widget/archive/archiveWebDayRest.jsp?d=2010-06-19'
html = etree.HTML(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

for link in html.xpath("//li[@data-section='Chennai']/a"):
    print '{} => {}'.format(link.text, link.attrib['href'])
```

Comment: is the syntax of ur code correct. I am getting an error of `Invalid Syntax`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's Okay. Note that you need to have [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) module installed to use that. It's a faster alternative to BeautifulSoup in many things. :)

Comment: yeah I have it installed. I was getting an error of above nature in the last line of print statement.

Comment: Can you please run the code that you mentioned and check ? also tell me the version of Python that you are using.

Comment: @casanova I've successfully tried this piece of code on Python 2.7.5. If you're using Python 2.5 or lower you don't have string `format()` method, in this case you could replace this line with `print '%s (%s)' % (link.text, link.attrib['href'])`. :)

Comment: kz .. now I got the result. However, if I use `Chennai` instead of `Business` I dont get anything printed. Can you helo me out on this issue too ?

Comment: @casanova Well, I didn't found any `<li data-section="Chennai">` on that page source, are you sure you're scraping the right URL for that?

Comment: it is there but under a different tag of `ul` where it is written `archiveRestDayList`. But anyways, thanks for your help. I got the problem sorted out. I used `selenium` module instead of `BeautifulSoup` which worked just fine.

Comment: @casanova You're welcome! I got it, it's being dynamically rendered on the page... To fetch `data-section='Chennai'` links you'll have to replace the URL with http://www.thehindu.com/template/1-0-1/widget/archive/archiveWebDayRest.jsp?d=2010-06-19, I've updated my answer accordingly! :)